How to systematically compute the quotient of free abelian groups (for simplicial homology)
I recently read an article that states that the quotient group G/H = <a+b, c>/<a+b-c, a+b+c> is equal to the quotient group <‎c>/<2c>. From what I understand, the fact that a+b-c belongs to the same coset as 0 gives rise to the relation a+b = c. This relation allows us to express cosets of the form nc+H (where n is an arbitrary integer) as cosets of the form n(a+b)+H. We can therefore substitute a+b with c in the quotient group to produce the group <c, c>/<c-c, c+c> = <‎c>/<2c>.
Although I can understand the formulaic approach to simplifying quotient groups, I simply don't know what's going on algebraically. Why is it that the fact that a+b = c (mod H) allows us to replace all instances of a+b with c? What kind of resources can I use to develop a systematic, theoretical understanding of the simplification of quotients of free abelian groups?
To give any answerers a more detailed idea of my understanding pertaining to this topic, here is how I would compute the first simplicial homology group of the torus using this diagram and a Δ-complex structure:
H2(T) = Ker(∂1)/Im(∂2) = <a,b,c>/<a+b-c> since a, b, and c are mapped to 0 by the first boundary homomorphism ∂1 and ∂2(n1U+n2L) = (n1+n2)(a+b-c), where n1 and n2 are arbitrary integers. Furthermore, since a+b-c and 0 belong to the same homology class (namely, 0+Im(∂2)), each homology class of the form nc+Im(∂2) can be expressed as a homology class of the form n(a+b)+Im(∂2). More explicitly, c+Im(∂2) = {..., c-2(a+b-c), c-(a+b-c), c, c+(a+b-c), c+2(a+b-c), ...} = {..., -2a-2b+3c, -a-b+2c, c, a+b, 2a+2b-c, ...} and a+b+Im(∂2) = {..., a+b-2(a+b-c), a+b-(a+b-c), a+b, a+b+(a+b-c), a+b+2(a+b-c), ...} = {..., -a-b+2c, c, a+b, 2a+2b-c, 3a+3b-c, ...}. From this computation, it is clear to see that the homology classes [a+b] and [c] are equivalent. Hence, H2(T) is isomorphic to ℤ⊕ℤ.
Although the above strategy has worked for me when computing the simplicial homology groups of simpler objects like the torus and the unit circle S1, I find it difficult to compute more complicated quotient groups, such as the first simplicial homology group of ℝP2. I have looked in threads that are similar to this one, and came across an answer that mentioned the first isomorphism theorem. However, if I'm not mistaken, the first isomorphism theorem is a tool that is primarily used to prove the existence of isomorphisms between groups and does not represent a method by which quotients of free abelian groups may be simplified.
Thank you.

You can do this by computing the Smith normal form of the relation matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form

Here's a MathJax tutorial :)
